# Multi-release log4j-api-2.11.0.jar on the the module-path in javadoc 10.0.2

Tags: java, javadoc, log4j2, java-10, multi-release-jar

I'm trying to javadoc code that contains a `module-info.java` that `requires org.apache.logging.log4j;`.

I've included the jar from Maven Central that matches the coordinates `"org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.0` (which is a multi-release jar) on the module path.

`javac` compiles the code fine, but the following simplified `javadoc` command outputs an error:

```
javadoc --module-path ./log4j-api-2.11.0.jar -d ~/Desktop ./src/main/java/module-info.java
```

Error:

> error: module not found: org.apache.logging.log4j
>       requires org.apache.logging.log4j;

When I manually repackaged `log4j-api-2.11.0.jar` as a non-multi-release jar, the `javadoc` worked (the simplified command above outputs an error about `No public or protected classes found to document`, but my real command works, and that error shows that the simplified command has progressed past the `module not found` error).

Does javadoc (from Oracle JDK 10.0.2+13) not support multi-release jars on the module-path?

Or is there something wrong with `log4j-api-2.11.0.jar` that can be fixed while still maintaining it as a multi-release jar?

Comment: A little confusion, what is your real command versus simplified command in the question? Would be even better to see the real command along with the javac command used to compile the code.

Comment: It had more Java source files & additional (non-multi-release) jars on the module path. All the modules from the other jars were properly found by javadoc.

Comment: I guess the actual question must include, **How does one generate javadoc for `module-info.java`?**, I fail to understand how does one solve *No public or protected classes found to document* for the module descriptor as well. And that's what I would search further for if there exists a solution.

Comment: The second problem goes away when I actually include other source files in the javadoc arguments. I just didn’t want to write a really long command line on SO, so I left them out. Someone from log4j confirmed that javadoc doesn’t work with their jar, so they’ve filed a bug report with Oracle https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/LOG4J2-2393/comment/16556420

Comment: Maybe Oracle will point out some flaw in the log4j multi-release jar, but, given that it works with javac, it’s more likely that javadoc is just buggy.

Comment: Yeah, was giving it a try with default IDE (IntelliJ) Javadoc generation and seems like there is definitely something incorrect with `javadoc` when the `module-info` resides within the *META-INF/*...from the link, the current solution would be to fall back to **log4j-api-2.10.0.jar** which is also a multi-release jar though. Hopefully you are not using anything specific to the release 2.11.0 in that case though.

Comment: I don’t need to generate javadocs myself. I’m modifying the Gradle experimental-jigsaw plugin to work more correctly for additional tasks, source sets, etc. I got this error when testing. I just wanted to ensure that my command-line options were not at fault, or possibly easily fix the error so I could help log4j improve their jar. This error isn’t a blocker for me (as long as it wasn’t my code’s fault); it just prevents me from testing javadoc on certain inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a a bug in the Javadoc tool and has been reported to Oracle. See https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8208269.

Comment: The bug has been fixed, but only in Java 12. So at the time of writing it still doesn't work in the latest LTS release.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by you in the comments, this seems to be an issue with `javadoc` tool when the `module-info.class` resides in the [META-INF/versions/9](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/LOG4J2-2393/comment/16556420) .

Looking at the [`2.11.0` release notes](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/RELEASE-NOTES.md#apache-log4j-2110-release-notes), the core doesn't have much implementation changes, and one can make use of the **`org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.10.0`** to stay on the multi-release jar of `log4j-api` and get it working with `javadoc` tool to generate the documents.

I can confirm the above works both with IDE(IntelliJ) and command line.